# How to update Map using monocle

Tags: scala, lenses, monocle-scala

I'd like to try [Monocle](https://github.com/julien-truffaut/Monocle) library.
But i could not find help resources for base syntax.

In short i need optics `Map[K,V] -> A` having optics `V -> A`, how could i define this?

Suppose i have some

```
import monocle.macros.GenLens

case class DirState(opened: Boolean)

object DirState {
  val opened = GenLens[DirState](_.opened)
}

type Path = List[String]
type StateStore = Map[Path, DirState]
```

Next I encounter place where i need simple `StateStore => StateStore`, so  I'm importing

```
import monocle._
import monocle.std._
import monocle.syntax._
import monocle.function._
```

And trying to define first:

```
def setOpened(path: Path): StateStore => StateStore = 
  at(path) composeLens DirState.opened set true
```

Getting here

> ambiguous implicit values:  both method `atMap` in `trait MapInstances` of
>   type `[K, V]=> monocle.function.At[Map[K,V],K,V]`  and method `atSet` in
>   `trait SetInstances` of type `[A]=> monocle.function.At[Set[A],A,Unit]` 
>   match expected type
>   `monocle.function.At[S,Path,A]`

Trying to change my definition to

```
def setOpened(path: Path): StateStore => StateStore =
  index(path) composeLens DirState.opened set true
```

Getting now:

> type mismatch;  found   :
>   `monocle.function.Index[Map[Path,Nothing],Path,Nothing]`
>       (which expands to)  `monocle.function.Index[Map[List[String],Nothing],List[String],Nothing]`
>   required:
>   `monocle.function.Index[Map[Path,Nothing],Path,A]`
>       (which expands to) `monocle.function.Index[Map[List[String],Nothing],List[String],A]`
>
> Note:
>   `Nothing <: A`, but `trait Index` is invariant in type `A`. You may wish to
>   define `A` as `+A` instead. (SLS 4.5)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import monocle.function.index._
import monocle.std.map._
import monocle.syntax._

def setOpened(path: Path)(s: StateStore): StateStore =
  (s applyOptional index(path) composeLens DirState.opened).set(true)
```

let's have a look at the type of `index`

```
def index[S, I, A](i: I)(implicit ev: Index[S, I, A]): Optional[S, A] = 
  ev.index(i)

trait Index[S, I, A] {
  def index(i: I): Optional[S, A]
}
```

So `index` summon an instance of type class `Index` of type `Index[S, I, A]`. 
This permits to use `index` for `Map`, `List`, `Vector` and so on.

The problem is that scala compiler needs to infer 3 types: `S`, `I` and `A` at the call site of `index`. `I` is easy, it is the type of the parameter you pass to `index`. However,`S` and `A` are only know when you call `set`.

The `apply` syntax has been created to guide type inference for such scenario, basically `applyOptional`captures `S` which is `Map[Path, DirState]`. This gives enough information for the compiler to infer `A =:= DirState`.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of examples of how to do this and many other handy tips are available in the Monocle repo:

https://github.com/julien-truffaut/Monocle/blob/master/example/src/test/scala/monocle/function/

More specificically for this scenario:
https://github.com/julien-truffaut/Monocle/blob/master/example/src/test/scala/monocle/function/FilterIndexExample.scala